# Center text in navbar with image in Ionic framework

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I would like to have my text in the middle of an image inside a navbar. I have this code but the text aligns horizontally with the circle image. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <div *ngIf="showHeaderInfo">
      <ion-title>
        <div style="background-color: #4989ff; color: whitesmoke;" >
          <img class="circle-pic-header" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;" src="{{userInfo?.image}}" />
            {{ userInfo?.firstName }} {{ userInfo?.lastName }}
        </div>
      </ion-title>
    </div>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logOutHandler()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know but I can suggest you to use `center` tag though

Comment: I tried putting the center on the first div and tried enclosing the {{userInfor?firstName}}... inside a span with center. still it didn't work.

Comment: Hummmm ... Let me try to find something else

Comment: Are you using Angular.js ?

Comment: `layout-align="center center"` this can be used in Angular,js

Comment: add css on parent div `text-align:center'`

Comment: @Chilll007: I tried this one `<div *ngIf="showHeaderInfo" text-align:center>` still a no go. It only placed the whole div in the center. The text is still inlined with the image

Comment: @MasterDarkNight: the layout-align didn't do the trick either..

Comment: I got it , problem is with image not the content. The image is in block , hence the text starts after the image ends which is lower part of image. What you are trying to do is to display the image next to image , which is middle not the lower portion. [Live demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_align). You can use align attribute in image to solve your problem.  You can also use css in image tag. Hope it is what you want , If this is not your problem then reply again.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add CSS property on image to vertically align text at the center like this

Make sure that there is no display:block on image element

```css
.circle-pic-header{vertical-align:middle}
```

[You can find JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hz1hpoh/)